# percentage of reduction and log transformed

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have the following model:

log(Y) = Intercept + beta1 * X + Error

-> interpretatoion: "One unit increase in X is associated with a (beta1 * 100) percent 
   increase in Y".

And now  i wish have the beta1 of 30 pourcent of Y reduction. How to get it? ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this perhaps a homework question? If so, please add a "self-study" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear.

Assuming,
$$ ln(Y_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i $$
Let $y_i = ln(Y_i)$
Then,
$$ \hat{y}^{'} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{'} $$
$$ \hat{y}^{"} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x^{"} $$
$$ \hat{y}^{"} - \hat{y}^{'} = \beta_1 ( x^{"} - x^{'}) $$
$$ ln \left( \frac{Y^{"}}{Y^{'}} \right) = \beta_1 ( x^{"} - x^{'}) $$
$$ \frac{Y^{"}}{Y^{'}} = e^{\beta_1 ( x^{"} - x^{'})} $$
A 30% reduction in $Y_i$ would make:
$$ 70\% = e^{\beta_1 ( x^{"} - x^{'})} $$
$$ ln (70\%) = \beta_1 ( x^{"} - x^{'}) $$
$$ \frac{ln (70\%)}{\beta_1} = x^{"} - x^{'} $$

Since your x variable is in levels, there is no clear interpretation for "a n% change in x is associated with a $\beta_1$ * n% change in y." An simple example in economics may be to calculate the *elasticity* of y with respect to x (at the mean).